# Stack smashing while casting and copying from one buffer to another

Tags: c

I have a problem writing 8 alphanumeric symbols into my dest_buffer buffer.

I want to convert a char from buff to hexadecimal, then store the value in
different cases of my dest_buffer buffer.

For example:

buff[0] = 58 should give me dest_buffer[0] = '3' and dest_buffer[1] = 'a'
and so on to reach 8 chars.

src is a char[8*sizeof(int)+1] and buff is the same.
Unfortunatly, I only have this output:

```
2dbb771
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
[1]    9843 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

This is the loop I use to do the job

```
for (i = 0; i < 4*sizeof(int); ++i)
{
    snprintf (
        &dest_buff[i*sizeof(int)*2], 
        sizeof(int)*2, 
        "%x", 
        *(int*)&buff[i * sizeof(int)]
        ) ;
}
```

I know I'm missing something but I don't know what, neither where, could 
any of you help me?
Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

Here is another part of my code to be more precise:

```
int  i, rndf ;
char buff[4*sizeof(int)+1];

rndf = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) ;
if( read (rndf, buff, 4*sizeof(int)) < 0)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", "An error occured while reading urandom") ;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
}
close(rndf) ;
```

after this come the loop

Comment: Stack overflow maybe? What is `dest_buff`? Its size is?

Comment: @tilz0R I guess, but I couldn't find where and why, I'm stuck here

Comment: show us all code not just for loop. How is initialized, etc.

Comment: @tilz0R It's done

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. You violate the effective type rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stack corruption because `char buff[4*sizeof(int)+1];` is your variable.

Let's assume `sizeof(int)` is `4` bytes. Then variable size is `17` bytes.

By doing this: `&dest_buff[i*sizeof(int)*2]` you are at some time accessing (when `i = 3`) address offset `3 * 4 * 2 = 24` which is out of range of your variable.

Conclusion: you have *undefined behaviour*. Increase variable length or correct you pointer usage.

Comment: thanks, I'll be looking to fix my pointer, it helped me a lot !

Comment: Out of range is not the primary problem.

Comment: @Olaf after another code review, we infact don't know what is the problem because there is no visible size of `dest_buff`, therefore my answer is useless.

Comment: @tilz0R dest_buff and buff are the same size